# Declaring variables with this or var?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between declaring a variable with `this` or `var` ?

```
var foo = 'bar'
```

or

```
this.foo = 'bar'
```

When do you use `this` and when `var`?

edit: is there a simple question i can ask my self when deciding if i want to use `var` or `this`

Comment: For constructors, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is [*global code*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2.1) (the code is not part of any function), then you are creating a property on the global object with the two snippets, since `this` in [global code](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2.1) points to the global object.

The difference in this case is that when the `var` statement is used, that property cannot be deleted, for example:

```
var foo = 'bar';
delete foo; // false
typeof foo; // "string"

this.bar = 'baz';
delete bar; // true
typeof bar; "undefined"
```

<sub>(*Note:* The above snippet will behave differently in the Firebug console, since it runs code with *eval*, and the code executed in the *Eval Code* execution context permits the deletion of identifiers created with `var`, try it [here](http://jsbin.com/ukoya4/))</sub>

If the code is part of a function you should know that the `this` keyword has nothing to do with the function scope, is a reserved word that is set implicitly, depending how a function is called, for example:

*1* - When a function is called as a method (the function is invoked as member of an object):

```
obj.method(); // 'this' inside method will refer to obj
```

*2* - A normal function call:

```
myFunction(); // 'this' inside the function will refer to the Global object
// or 
(function () {})();
```

*3* - When the new operator is used:

```
var obj = new Constructor(); // 'this' will refer to a newly created object.
```

And you can even set the `this` value explicitly, using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methods, for example:

```
function test () {
  alert(this);
}
test.call("hello!"); //alerts hello!
```

You should know also that JavaScript has **function scope** only, and variables declared with the `var` statement will be reachable only within the same function or any inner functions defined below.

**Edit:** Looking the code you posted to the [@David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709869/declaring-variables-with-this-or-var/2709876#2709876), let me comment:

```
var test1 = 'test';  // two globals, with the difference I talk
this.test2 = 'test'; // about in the beginning of this answer

//...

function test4(){
    var test5 = 'test in function with var'; // <-- test5 is locally scoped!!!
    this.test6 = 'test in function with this'; // global property, see below
}

test4(); // <--- test4 will be called with `this` pointing to the global object
         // see #2 above, a call to an identifier that is not an property of an
         // object causes it

alert(typeof test5); // "undefined" since it's a local variable of `test4` 
alert(test6); // "test in function with this"
```

You can't access the `test5` variable outside the function because is locally scoped, and it exists only withing the scope of that function.

**Edit:** In response to your comment

For declaring variables I encourage you to always use `var`, it's what is made for.

The concept of the `this` value, will get useful when you start working with [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function), objects and methods.

Comment: You're welcome @meo, if anything is not clear don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: is there a simple question i can ask my self when deciding if i want to use `var` or `this`?

Comment: @meo, for *declaring variables* use always `var`, is what is made for.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `var`, the variable is scoped to the current function.

If you use `this`, then you are assigning a value to a property on whatever `this` is (which is either the object the method is being called on or (if the `new` keyword has been used) the object being created.

Comment: so how it comes that i can't access to var test5 but i can to test6 in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ew3pD/ ?

Comment: @meo Because test 5 loses it's scope once test 4 function is left.  When you're calling this.test6, you're creating a variable on the global scope because the function isn't being called on an object.

Comment: @meo: test6 is being assigned to `this` when a function is called without context object the global object is assumed.  Properties create on the global object are synonymous (but identical to) variables created at the global level.  You cannot create a property on the global object with the same name as a variable at the global level because they are both held against the global object.

Answer (score 3):

```
var foo = 'bar'
```

This will scope the `foo` variable to the function wrapping it, or the global scope.

```
this.foo = 'bar'
```

This will scope the `foo` variable to the `this` object, it exactly like doing this:

```
window.foo = 'bar';
```

or

```
someObj.foo = 'bar';
```

The second part of your question seems to be what is the `this` object, and that is something that is determined by what context the function is running in. [You can change what `this` is by using the apply method that all functions have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply). You can also make the default of the `this` variable an object other than the global object, by:

```
someObj.foo = function(){
  // 'this' is 'someObj'
};
```

or

```
function someObj(x){
  this.x=x;
}
someObj.prototype.getX = function(){
  return this.x;
}
var myX = (new someObj(1)).getX(); // myX == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `var` when you want to define a simple local variable as you would in a typical function:-

```
function doAdd(a, b)
{
  var c = a + b;
  return c;
}

var result = doAdd(a, b);

alert(result);
```

However `this` has special meaning when `call` is used on a function.

```
function doAdd(a, b)
{
   this.c = a + b;
}

var o = new Object();
doAdd.call(o, a, b);
alert(o.c);
```

You note the first parameter when using `call` on doAdd is the object created before.  Inside that execution of doAdd `this` will refer to that object. Hence it creates a `c` property on the object.

Typically though a function is assigned to a property of an object like this:-

```
function doAdd(a, b)
{
   this.c = a + b;
}

var o = new Object();
o.doAdd = doAdd;
```

Now the function can be execute using the . notation:-

```
o.doAdd(a, b);    
alert(o.c);
```

Effectively `o.doAdd(a, b)` is `o.doAdd.call(o, a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

In a constructor, you can use var to simulate private members and this to simulate public members:

```
function Obj() {
  this.pub = 'public';
  var priv = 'private';
}

var o = new Obj();
o.pub;    // 'public'
o.priv;   // error
```

Comment: Actually `o.priv;` doesn't makes an error, it will just return `undefined` :)

Answer (score 1):

Example for *this* and *var* explained below:

```
function Car() {
   this.speed = 0;

   var speedUp = function() {
      var speed = 10; // default
      this.speed = this.speed + speed; // see how this and var are used
   };

   speedUp();
}
```

Comment: Note that the `this` value of the `speedUp` function will be always the global object, since it's invoked with no *object context* (`speedUp();`), it has nothing to do with the outer `this.speed`, unless the `Car` function is called without the `new` operator. In that case `this` in the outer function will refer also to the global object, leaking a `speed` global variable (`window.speed`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = 'bar'; // 'var can be only used inside a function
```

and

```
this.foo = 'bar' // 'this' can be used globally inside an object
```