# Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

In C++, the language I'm most comfortable with, usually one declares an object like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
    int bar;
    int getBar() { return bar; }
}
```

Calling `getBar()` works fine (ignoring the fact that `bar` might be uninitialized). The variable `bar` within `getBar()` is in the scope of class `foo`, so I don't need to say `this->bar` unless I really need to make it clear that I'm referring to the class' `bar` instead of, say, a parameter.

Now, I'm trying to get started with OOP in Javascript. So, I look up how to define classes and try the same sort of thing:

```
function foo()
{
     this.bar = 0;
     this.getBar = function() { return bar; }
}
```

And it gives me `bar is undefined`. Changing the `bar` to `this.bar` fixes the issue, but doing that for every variable clutters up my code quite a bit. Is this necessary for every variable? Since I can't find any questions relating to this, it makes me feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

---

EDIT: Right, so, from the comments what I'm getting is that `this.bar`, a property of an object, references something different than `bar`, a local variable. Can someone say why exactly this is, in terms of scoping and objects, and if there's another way to define an object where this isn't necessary?

Comment: `.bar` is an object property, not a variable. So yes, to get the property from an object, you need to do so via some reference to that object. If `this` references your object, then `this.bar` will give you that property.

Comment: `this.bar` is not the same as `bar`. However you can do `var bar = this.bar` which will make `bar` reference `this.bar`

Comment: @Loktar but only if `this.bar` is an object or an array...

Comment: @Loktar: To be clear for OP, it'll get a copy of its current value.

Comment: @user1689607 it'll get a copy of its current value, if it's a primitive, or it'll get a "copy of the reference" to the object, if it's an object or an array.

Comment: Regarding your deeper question, made explicit in the edit, see [Why is there no implicit this in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4876073/1048572)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

JavaScript has no <s>classes</s> class-based object model. It uses the mightier prototypical inheritance, which can mimic classes, but is not suited well for it. Everything is an object, and objects [can] inherit from other objects.

A constructor is just a function that assigns properties to newly created objects. The object (created by a call with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)) can be referenced trough the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (which is local to the function).

A method also is just a function which is called *on* an object - again with `this` pointing to the object. At least when that function is invoked as a property of the object, using a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) (dot, brackets). This causes lots of confusion to newbies, because if you pass around that function (e.g. to an event listener) it is "detached" from the object it was accessed on.

Now where is the inheritance? Instances of a "class" inherit from the same prototype object. Methods are defined as function properties on that object (instead of one function for each instance), the instance on which you call them just inherits that property.

Example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = "foo"; // creating a property on the instance
}
Foo.prototype.foo = 0; // of course you also can define other values to inherit
Foo.prototype.getBar = function() {
    // quite useless
    return this.bar;
}

var foo = new Foo; // creates an object which inherits from Foo.prototype,
                   // applies the Foo constructor on it and assigns it to the var
foo.getBar(); // "foo" - the inherited function is applied on the object and
              // returns its "bar" property
foo.bar; // "foo" - we could have done this easier.
foo[foo.bar]; // 0 - access the "foo" property, which is inherited
foo.foo = 1;  // and now overwrite it by creating an own property of foo
foo[foo.getBar()]; // 1 - gets the overwritten property value. Notice that
(new Foo).foo;     // is still 0
```

So, we did only use properties of that object and are happy with it. But all of them are "public", and can be overwritten/changed/deleted! If that doesn't matter you, you're lucky. You can indicate "privateness" of properties by prefixing their names with underscores, but that's only a hint to other developers and may not be obeyed (especially in error).

So, clever minds have found a solution that uses the constructor function as a closure, allowing the creating of private "attributes". Every execution of a javascript function creates a new variable environment for local variables, which may get garbage collected once the execution has finished. Every function that is declared inside that scope also has access to these variables, and as long as those functions could be called (e.g. by an event listener) the environment must persist. So, by *exporting locally defined functions* from your constructor you preserve that variable environment with local variables that can only be accessed by these functions.

Let's see it in action:

```
function Foo() {
    var bar = "foo"; // a local variable
    this.getBar = function getter() {
        return bar; // accesses the local variable
    }; // the assignment to a property makes it available to outside
}

var foo = new Foo; // an object with one method, inheriting from a [currently] empty prototype
foo.getBar(); // "foo" - receives us the value of the "bar" variable in the constructor
```

This getter function, which is defined inside the constructor, is now called a "*privileged* method" as it has access to the "private" (local) "attributes" (variables). The value of `bar` will never change. You also could declare a setter function for it, of course, and with that you might add some validation etc.

Notice that the methods on the prototype object do not have access to the local variables of the constructor, yet they might use the privileged methods. Let's add one:

```
Foo.prototype.getFooBar = function() {
    return this.getBar() + "bar"; // access the "getBar" function on "this" instance
}
// the inheritance is dynamic, so we can use it on our existing foo object
foo.getFooBar(); // "foobar" - concatenated the "bar" value with a custom suffix
```

So, you can combine both approaches. Notice that the privileged methods need more memory, as you create distinct function objects with different scope chains (yet the same code). If you are going to create incredibly huge amounts of instances, you should define methods only on the prototype.

It gets even a little more complicated when you are setting up inheritance from one "class" to another - basically you have to make the child prototype object inherit from the parent one, and apply the parent constructor on child instances to create the "private attributes". Have a look at [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572), [Private variables in inherited prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617139/1048572), [Define Private field Members and Inheritance in JAVASCRIPT module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12463040/1048572) and [How to implement inheritance in JS Revealing prototype pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9248655/1048572)

Comment: This helps a lot with my understanding of what exactly is going on here. Really, the original motivator was just me being annoyed with having to put `this` in front of everything, but actually understanding why I have to is good.

Comment: There is no “member operator” in ECMAScript. The proper term is “[property accessor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) notation”.

Comment: @PointedEars: Sure, that's the official term. But is "member operator" (seemingly coined by MDN) really wrong or non-descriptive? Operator in a mathematical sense of course, not in terms of binary ES operator (§11.5-11.11)

Comment: The misnomer likely originates from David Flanagan’s “JavaScript: The Definitive Guide” (which is anything *but* “definitive”) where he actually lists `[`…`]` as “array operator”. Yes, that *is* wrong. Consider the possible “operands”. And what would be the operator precedence, particularly for `[`…`]`? I have just edited that patently wrong MDN article, and suggested that it be moved out of the “Operators” namespace. You should update your link and re-check it after a while.

Comment: *array* operator is "definitive" wrong, yes :-) [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) makes sense to me, giving it the highest possible precedence (after grouping operators). Nonetheless, a big thanks for improving MDN :-) Notice that the [operators page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) also <s>lists</s>listed `get`/`set`, `let`, `this` and even `function` as operators :-/

Comment: If it were an operator, the operand(s) would have to be resolved *before* the operation is performed. Mathematics does apply here: An operation has one or more operands of a specific type each, and the result of the operation is of a specific type (sometimes depending on the type of the operands). None of this applies at least to the dot property accessor (which is probably why Flanagan thought `[`…`]` would be an operator), and the latter does not apply to the bracket property accessor. Re MDN: You're welcome. Apparently there is still a lot to do there.

Answer (score 7):

Explicitly saying `this.foo` means (as you've understood well) that you're interested about the property `foo` of the current object referenced by `this`. So if you use: `this.foo = 'bar';` you're going to set the property `foo` of the current object referenced by `this` equals to `bar`.

The `this` keyword in JavaScript doesn't always mean the same thing like in C++. Here I can give you an example:

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
   console.log(this); //Developer {language: "js", name: "foo"} if called by Developer
}

function Developer(name, language) {
   this.language = language;
   Person.call(this, name);
}

var dev = new Developer('foo', 'js');
```

In the example above we're calling the function `Person` with the context of the function `Developer` so `this` is referencing to the object which will be created by `Developer`. As you might see from the `console.log` result `this` is comes from `Developer`. With the first argument of the method `call` we specify the context with which the function will be called.

If you don't use `this` simply the property you've created will be a local variable. As you might know JavaScript have functional scope so that's why the variable will be local, visible only for the function where it's declared (and of course all it's child functions which are declared inside the parent). Here is an example:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 'foobar';
    this.getBar = function () {
        return bar;
    }
}

var f = new foo();
console.log(f.getBar());  //'foobar'
```

This is true when you use the `var` keyword. This means that you're defining `bar` as local variable if you forget `var` unfortunately `bar` will became global.

```
function foo() {
    bar = 'foobar';
    this.getBar = function () {
        return bar;
    }
}

var f = new foo();
console.log(window.bar);  //'foobar'
```

Exactly the local scope can help you to achieve privacy and encapsulation which are one of the greatest benefits of OOP.

Real world example:

```
function ShoppingCart() {
    var items = [];

    this.getPrice = function () {
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
          total += items[i].price;
       }
       return total;
    }

    this.addItem = function (item) {
        items.push(item);
    }

    this.checkOut = function () {
        var serializedItems = JSON.strigify(items);
        //send request to the server...
    }
}

var cart = new ShoppingCart();
cart.addItem({ price: 10, type: 'T-shirt' });
cart.addItem({ price: 20, type: 'Pants' });
console.log(cart.getPrice()); //30
```

---

One more example of the benefits of the JavaScript scope is the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).
In Module Pattern you can simulate privacy using the local functional scope of JavaScript. With this approach you can have both private properties and methods. Here is an example:

```
var module = (function {

    var privateProperty = 42;

    function privateMethod() {
        console.log('I\'m private');
    }
    return {

       publicMethod: function () {
           console.log('I\'m public!');
           console.log('I\'ll call a private method!');
           privateMethod();
       },

       publicProperty: 1.68,

       getPrivateProperty: function () {
           return privateProperty;
       },

       usePublicProperty: function () {
           console.log('I\'ll get a public property...' + this.publicProperty);
       }

    }
}());

module.privateMethod(); //TypeError
module.publicProperty(); //1.68
module.usePublicProperty(); //I'll get a public property...1.68
module.getPrivateProperty(); //42
module.publicMethod(); 
/*
 * I'm public!
 * I'll call a private method!
 * I'm private
 */
```

There's a little strange syntax with the parentless wrapping the anonymous functions but forget it for the moment (it's just executing the function after it's being initialized). The functionality can be saw from the example of usage but the benefits are connected mainly of providing a simple public interface which does not engages you with all implementation details. For more detailed explanation of the pattern you can see the link I've put above.

---

I hope that with `this` :-) information I helped you to understand few basic topics of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 0;
  this.getBar = function () { return this.bar };
}
```

When you call the function above with the `new` keyword - like this...

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

... - a few things happen:

1) an object is created
2) the function is executed with the `this` keyword referencing that object.
3) that object is returned.

`foo`, then, becomes this object:

```
{
    bar: 0,
    getBar: function () { return this.bar; }
};
```

Why not, then, just do this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: 0,
    getBar: function () { return this.bar; }
};
```

You would, if it's just that one simple object.

But creating an object with a constructor (that's how it's called) gives us a big advantage in creating multiple of the "same" objects.

See, in javascript, all functions are created with a prototype property [an object], and all objects created with that function (by calling it with the new keyword) are linked to that prototype object. This is why it's so cool - you can store all common methods (and properties, if you wanted to) in the prototype object, and save a lot of memory. This is how it works:

```
function Foo( bar, bob ) {
   this.bar = bar;
   this.bob = bob;
}

Foo.prototype.calculate = function () {
  // 'this' points not to the 'prototype' object 
  // as you could've expect, but to the objects
  // created by calling Foo with the new keyword.
  // This is what makes it work.
  return this.bar - this.bob;  
};

var foo1 = new Foo(9, 5);
var foo2 = new Foo(13, 3);
var result1 = foo1.calculate();
var result2 = foo2.calculate();

console.log(result1); //logs 4
console.log(result2); //logs 10
```

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

To get closer to OOP in JavaScript, you might want to take a look into a Module design pattern (for instance, described [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)).

Based on the closure effect, this pattern allows emulating private properties in your objects.

With 'private' properties you can reference them directly by its identifier (i.e., no `this` keyword as in constructors).

But anyway, closures and design patterns in JS - an advanced topic. So, get familiar with basics (also explained in the book mentioned before).

Comment: Going back and looking through this article (it certainly has the length to be a book, but it does not seem to be published) has been very, very helpful. Thanks for bringing this under my eye.

Comment: @Chaosed0 Always welcome! Not that many books/articles on design patterns in JS are worth reading, but this one is good.

Comment: @JohnDoe they have since created javascript modules but since working with them over the last year i am still running into scope related issues. related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77712503/a-way-to-enable-default-this-scope-in-a-js-to-not-require-binding-this-or-prefac

Answer (score 2):

In javascript `this` always refers to the owner object of the function. For example, if you define your function `foo()` in a page, then owner is the javascript object `windows`; or if you define the `foo()` on html element `<body>`, then the owner is the html element body; and likewise if you define the function onclick of element `<a>`, then the owner is the anchor.

In your case, you are assigning a property `bar` to the 'owner' object at the begining and trying to return the local variable `bar`.

Since you never defined any local varialbe `bar`, it is giving you as bar is undefined.

Ideally your code should have defined the variable as `var bar;` if you want to return the value zero.

Answer (score 1):

*this* is like a public access modifier of objects(variables or functions), while *var* is the private access modifier

Example

```
var x = {}; 
x.hello = function(){
    var k = 'Hello World'; 
   this.m = 'Hello JavaScript'; 
}

var t = new x.hello(); 
console.log(t.k); //undefined
console.log(t.m); //Hello JavaScript
```